# Adding javascript to functions.php causes problems with my template

Tags: functions, javascript, wp-head

I want a "Read on" link that moves to another part of the page when clicked.

[I understand the HTML bit](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511) and [I have even used some nice scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/).

It works. But when implemented breaks part of my theme. The slider image is gone and the H1 text is all bunched up to the left.

Here is what I added to my child functions.php, in order to inject the javascript into the head area.

```
/**
 * Smooth scroll 
 */

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');
function wpse_43672_wp_head(){
    //Close PHP tags 
    ?>
    //ADD YOUR PLAIN CODE HERE

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>

    //STOP YOUR PLAIN CODE HERE

    <?php //Open PHP tags
}
```

How is this half breaking my template, but still scrolling nicely? Is there a better way?

Edit:

OK now I'm trying to enqueue the script.

Here is what I have in my child functions.php (have the js in a file). The template loads OK but he scroll isn't animating. I can't see an error in the inspector.

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('scroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('scroll');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Final edit:

Here is the solution I used...

I added this to the child functions.php

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('scroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('scroll');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

I added this to scroll.js file in a js folder in my child dir.

```
(function($){

        $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

I was in fact getting a js error and needed to add a [noConplict wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26819916/1901781).

Comment: I am sure you are including jQuery script (probably different versions) twice. Use `wp_enqueue_script` instead to add jQuery.

Comment: Remove the line `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and try

Comment: That fixes the page, but the smooth scrolling doesn't work. Clicking the link just teleports me to the new location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is already loaded with WordPress, so you won't need `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

When using jQuery with WordPress, you'll likely require no-conflict wrappers : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

There are likely JS errors being outputted in your browser console, so giving us more info on errors can prove useful as well.

There is definitely **a better way** - starting with this guide for enqueuing Javascript should give you solid grounds to understanding WP scripts a little better : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Comment: OK I removed the call to src jquery. It fixed the page, but broke the smooth scroll. I had two parts. The part to inject the code to the head, and the code to enable the javascript. Should both be enqueued?

Comment: You could try replace `$` with `jQuery` or wrap the entire function in a noConflict wrapper.

Might need to see some console log details to get a better idea of what's not working.

Comment: Updated with my enqueue attempt. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice one! Try using this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri instead of plugins_url and verify by inspecting page source, that your scroll script is actually getting enqueued.

Comment: One step ahead:) I had already made it that far. I updated the edit. The page loads fine but no scrolling. I can confirm that the .js file is loading from the right location and no other js errors are thrown:/

Comment: Did you try "replace $ with jQuery or wrap the entire function in a noConflict wrapper"

Comment: Yep just got it to work:) Thanks for the help. I'll update the question with my final solution. Replacing $ didn't work but the noConflict did. I have learned a lot!